# применимость метода ближайщих соседей.( Классификатор kNN)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, информатика

Есть таск:
Дана таблица из 10M строк, и длительность каждого из фильмов
1)необходимо разделить фильмы на длинные\короткие или более групп.
2)Найти скользящее среднее для каждого из этих сегментов
3)Найти какой-либо другой показатель / или выполнить какой-либо другой тип быстрого анализа, чтобы связать время просмотра с рейтингами. Обоснуйте ответ.

Первый пункт хотела бы сделать методом ближайщих соседей. Но не уверена в точности(((
Какой метод подсказали бы Вы?

```
movies['launch date'] = pd.to_datetime(movies['launch date'])
df = movies[['launch date', 'watch_time']]
df = df.sort_values(by='launch date')
df.head()

for i in range(0,df.shape[0]-2):
    df.loc[df.index[i+2],'SMA_3'] = np.round(((df.iloc[i,1]+ df.iloc[i+1,1] +df.iloc[i+2,1])/3),1)

df['pandas_SMA_4'] = df.iloc[:,1].rolling(window=4).mean()


plt.figure(figsize=[15,10])
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(df['watch_time'],label='data')
plt.plot(df['SMA_3'],label='SMA 3 Months')
plt.plot(df['pandas_SMA_4'],label='SMA 4 Months')
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

[image: average]

Comment: Переведите задания на русский язык

Comment: @dIm0n Короче, есть таблица из 10M строк, и длительность каждого из фильмов - необходимо разделить фильмы на длинные.короткие или более групп.

Comment: Используйте кнопку править под вопросом

Comment: @dIm0n это задание из области дата сайнс

Comment: Я понял :) Это же не означает, что оно должно быть на английском? Тут же ruSO

Comment: @dIm0n перевела

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем вам метод ближайших соседей, если ваша задача сводится к банальному бинингу? Или вам _нужно_ использовать KNN для ml?

Comment: @strawdog  я прросто никогда не слышала про бининг:))

Comment: @strawdog другой вопрос - как выбирать число биннов?

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova А вы постройте график распределения длительностей фильмов по всей выборке. И вот грубо говоря сколько там будет горбов, столько и надо делать бинов. Границы бинов делать по впадинам в графике распределения. Наверняка это можно и по-научному как-то сделать, но навскидку вижу так

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova А про скользящее среднее как-то непонятно вообще, обычно его строят там, где есть time series, то есть ось времени и ось чего-нибудь ещё. А, ну если только ось x будет длительность фильма, а y рейтинг... Но всё-равно не очень понятно, зачем тут скользящее среднее, логичнее было бы просто среднее по бинам посчитать. Но может я чего не знаю.

Comment: постройте гистограмму, увидите сами по выпуклостям графика.

Comment: @CrazyElf здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, про скользящее среднее. Заказчик настаивает на нем:)) 
Я добавила код и график  в вопрос.
Правильно ли я сделала?

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Что-то не вижу добавки (  А так то скользящее среднее в `Pandas` это `rolling(...)` и потом `mean()`

Comment: @CrazyElf добавила. Правильно ли я сделала?

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova По-хорошему вам надо было новый вопрос делать. Но так то вроде выглядит правильно, хотя картинку пока и не видно. Не понял только, почему вы "вручную" SMA_3 делали, надо было тоже через rolling и mean делать. А если вам округления не хватило, так оно так же через round есть в Pandas

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Поправил пост, что-то графики не выглядят правильными. Но мне пока некогда разбираться )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, смотрите. В самом первом приближении напрашивается разбиение на 3 группы:

1. Меньше часа
2. От часа до двух
3. Больше часа

Разбивать на корзины можно с помощью функции `Pandas cut`. Код для иллюстрации:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# https://datasets.imdbws.com/
titles_basic = pd.read_csv("title.basics.tsv.gz", sep='\t', na_values=r'\N')
movies = titles_basic[(titles_basic.titleType == 'movie') & (~titles_basic.runtimeMinutes.isna())].copy()
movies.runtimeMinutes = movies.runtimeMinutes.values.astype(np.float)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5));
sns.distplot(movies.runtimeMinutes[movies.runtimeMinutes < 180], bins=3);

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5));
movies['timetype'] = pd.cut(movies.runtimeMinutes, [-np.Inf,60,120,np.Inf], labels=['короткий', 'стандартный','длинный'])
sns.countplot(movies.timetype);
```

Гистограмма длительностей фильмов, разбитая на 3 корзины. Явно видны провалы графика примерно на 60 и 120 минут, поэтому я потом и сделал разбиение по этим значениям. В принципе, можно выделить в отдельную категорию также значения <45, ориентируясь опять же на график.
При этом если попробовать ставить в данной гистограмме другое количество корзин, ничего путного не нарисуется в результате.
Кроме того, заметьте, что я убрал из данных фильмы длительностью >180, если их оставить, там получается длинный хвост на гистограмме, не несущий никакой информации, полагаю, что можно считать это выбросами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сколько фильмов попало в соответствующие категории после разбиения на корзины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алгоритм KNN в том случае, когда можно провести простое разбиение по неким линиям, в общем-то не нужен. Хотя вы могли бы попробовать какую-нибудь кластеризацию ради интереса.

Насчёт скользящих средних я как-то тут не понял, обычно они применяются при анализе `Time Series`. Вычисляются они с помощью конструкции `rolling(<размер окна>).mean()`.

Comment: есть проблемка: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'titleType'

решение не работает:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163439/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-height

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova А у вас те же колонки в данных? Я вам сам принцип показал

Comment: ступила:) извините.

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Да нормально всё. Откуда я брал данные там в комментарии ссылка указана. У вас я не знаю откуда данные, может оттуда же, а может и нет, много где датасеты IMDB лежат в разной степени обработанности )

Answer (score 3):

Итак, читаем внимательно то, что вы написали.

Начнем с двух групп. Есть фильмы первой группы, каждый со своим рейтингом.
И есть фильмы второй группы, каждый со своим рейтингом.

Вопрос - отличаются ли статистически значимо рейтинги в группах. Поскольку у нас Рейтинги измерены в ранговой шкале, применяем непараметрический критерий. Ну например, можно *начать* с критерия Манна-Уитни.  В итоге получаем ответ на поставленный вопрос. ("Начать" - потому как есть и другие методы этой группы, которые могут оказаться более адекватными для ваших данных").
Если вы решите разбивать на большее количество групп, то нужно применять критерий Краскела-Уоллиса.

Если выявиться, что "да можно предположить статистически значимую зависимость рейтинга от времени просмотра", то  можно пойти дальше - строить регрессионную модель зависимости рейтинга от времени.

Если быть более корректным, то можно вместо регрессионной модели строить модель классификации "время-рейтинг". И вот тут вот появляется место для вашего критерия kNN (ближайших соседей).

Повторю, все это корректно, если указанные критерии покажут наличие зависимости. Кстати, я не упомянул о таком этапе, как выявление корреляции между вашими переменными -  только конечно не Пирсона, а Спирмана и/или Кэнделла. В противном случае - "отрицательный результат -  тоже результат".

В общем, на самом деле ваша задача не имеет однозначного решения. Поэтому нужно пробовать разные подходы, а потом сравнивать результаты и искать наиболее адекватные.

Comment: "Вопрос - отличаются ли статистически значимо рейтинги в группах." - вот как вы это смогли рассмотреть в вопросе? Наверняка что-то такое предполагалось, но из вопроса было сложно понять, что вообще требуется )

Comment: @CrazyElf - многолетний опыт работы с (толковыми :-) ) студентами и не менее толковыми заказчиками..  Так  что возможно ТС устроит просто даже выявление наличия корреляционной зависимости между показателями, и не более. (Но это мне пришло в голову "потом").